# Thread safety issue with CommonsWare 5.9 Event Buses example

Tags: android, commonsware

I have a thread safety issue/question regarding the CommonsWare 5.9 Event Buses example.

It looks to me like there is a problem with the way the `model` `ArrayList` is accessed from multiple threads.  If this works, I'd appreciate understanding why.

This code performs the declaration, initialization and populating of `model`.

```
private static final String[] items= { "lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
  "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi",
  "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis", "etiam",
  "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales",
  "pellentesque", "augue", "purus" };
private ArrayList<String> model=new ArrayList<String>();
private boolean isStarted=false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setRetainInstance(true);

  if (!isStarted) {
    isStarted=true;
    new LoadWordsThread().start();
  }
}

public ArrayList<String> getModel() {
  return(model);
}

class LoadWordsThread extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (String item : items) {
      if (!isInterrupted()) {
        model.add(item);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new WordReadyEvent());
        SystemClock.sleep(400);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It wakes up every 400 mSec and adds an entry to `model`.  The consumption of `model` is a little more complicated in that I don't readily have the code handy to post.  It's down somewhere inside an `ArrayAdapter`.  The consumption of the model is triggered by a call to `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

The issue/question I have is that `model` is written to in one thread (not the Android UI thread), but the consumption is happening on the UI thread.  All of the elements of the `model` `ArrayList` are immutable, which helps, but it still doesn't seem right to me.

If this code is in fact correct, I'd like to understand why.  Thanks, Lee.

Update:

I don't think my problem is with the event bus part.  I think I get that. It's almost more of a java issue I have in that model is written to in one thread (worker thread, code above) while theoretically it could be simultaneously read from in another thread (UI thread).  It seems to me that there needs to be some sort of concurrent access control in place on model.  A synchronized block or concurrent `ArrayList`.  But the ultimate consumer of the model is code that I don't have control over in my app, its down in `ArrayAdapter` somewhere. I can't add a synchronize to it.   Once the `ArrayAdapter` is initialized with a model, the `ArrayAdapter`owns it and will access it from the UI thread.  I'm not sure that a non-UI thread can modify model in this way.

Comment: Using greenRobots EventBus??. If so go through the link here https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, the example is using the greenrobot event bus.  I wasn't sure how much information to include from the sample.

Comment: read about Delivery Threads in the link posted. It will answer your question

Comment: Did you read the initial chapter on event buses in the book?

Comment: @CommonsWare The code I posted comes from p432 which is in the "Event Buses" chapter.  It is part of EventBus/AsyncDemo.  Is that the initial chapter on event buses?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from writing a custom adapter (extend BaseAdapter) vs just using a stock ArrayAdapter. Then you can use whatever type you want for your data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct -- this sample app is flawed. I was trying to aggressively minimize the code, and I went too far.

The two changes that are needed are:

1. `AsyncDemoFragment` should be working off of a copy of the model `ArrayList<String>`, initialized from the then-current model, rather than actually *being* the model
2. I should be supplying the word in `WordReadyEvent`, to allow the `AsyncDemoFragment` to update its copy of the model, in addition to firing `notifyDataSetChanged()`

This will allow the background thread to update and maintain the model master copy on the background thread, letting the UI thread know about changes as needed, and allowing the UI thread to retrieve a copy of that model for UI use.

In other scenarios, it's not out of the question to have a shared, synchronized model. That's impractical in this case, short of kcoppock's suggestion of creating a customized adapter class, which would be like swatting a fly with a Buick in this case.

I will work to fix this for the next book update.

BTW, the reason I asked whether you had read the chapter is simply because some people ask questions based solely on examining the repo, and I wanted to know if you had read the material that accompanied the sample. My comment could have been interpreted in suggesting that if you read the chapter you would have an answer to your question, and I definitely did not mean that. I apologize if my lousy phrasing caused you any problems.

Thanks for pointing out the issue!

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, another great answer.  No worries on the reading the chapter first comment.  My only concern when I read your comment was that I didn't RTFM before I sent out the question.  I was already working from the Event Buses chapter so I didn't want to find that it was all clearly explained previously.  I am a subscriber, is it too late or inappropriate go get a book bounty?

Comment: @Lee: Follow the procedure in the book's preface, and you're set.